# Trying to move items from list box WPF powershell project

Tags: wpf, powershell, listview

Trying to move and item or multiple if selected from one list box to another. The left list box is populated with users searched from AD. I then want to select one or multiple and move them to the right listbox. My issue is i cannot move them. Below code is the function to search and the move function. I am new to WPF so learning and playing to get some understanding. Hoping someone can assist in this.

```
    function SearchDGUserClick
{
    param($sender, $e)

$DGMemberSearchListBox.ItemsSource

$query = $DGUserSearchText.Text
$UserSearch = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'") | Select SamAccountName | Sort -Property SamaAccountName

$DGMemberSearchListBox.ItemsSource = $UserSearch

}

function AddUserClick
{
    param($sender, $e)


#$UserSearch should be an array or collection of user objects
$DGMemberSearchListBox.ItemsSource = $UserSearch

#Handle the button click or any other event that triggers the move
$selectedItems = @()

foreach ($item in $DGMemberSearchListBox.SelectedItems) {
    #If DGMemberAddListBox doesn't have the item yet, add it
    if ($DGMemberAddListBox.Items -notcontains $item) {
        $DGMemberAddListBox.Items.Add($item)
    }

    #Remove the item from DGMemberSearchListBox
    $selectedItems += $item
}

#Remove the selected items from DGMemberSearchListBox
foreach ($item in $selectedItems) {
    $DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Remove($item)
}

}
```

Tried playing around with this as well but when i run it, it searches user fine i can select one user, when i click move it clears the left and does not populate the right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `ItemsSource` property when you add or remove items from the `Items` collection of the `ListBox`. It's one way or another but not both.

Try this:

```
function SearchDGUserClick
{
  param($sender, $e)

  $query = $DGUserSearchText.Text
  $UserSearch = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'") | Select SamAccountName | Sort -Property SamaAccountName

  foreach ($item in $UserSearch) {
    $DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Add($item)
  }
}

function AddUserClick
{
  param($sender, $e)

  #Handle the button click or any other event that triggers the move
  $selectedItems = @()

  foreach ($item in $DGMemberSearchListBox.SelectedItems) {
    #If DGMemberAddListBox doesn't have the item yet, add it
    if ($DGMemberAddListBox.Items -notcontains $item) {
      $DGMemberAddListBox.Items.Add($item)
    }

    #Remove the item from DGMemberSearchListBox
    $selectedItems += $item
  }

  #Remove the selected items from DGMemberSearchListBox
  foreach ($item in $selectedItems) {
    $DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Remove($item)
  }
}
```

It should work assuming your first populate the `DGMemberSearchListBox` before you move the items to the `DGMemberAddListBox`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you... Appreciate the input.. That worked a treat. Also modified to remove from the other listbox if a mistake was made with another click...